# CRM 2011 Is there a way to union queries

Tags: view, dynamics-crm-2011

I am (actually my client is) interested in seeing a list of activities by their direction = outgoing on their dashboard.

The generic activity doesn't have the direction property but email, phone, fax, letter etc do.

How do I select all activities with direction=outgoing in a single view? effectively unioning the results of multiple queries.

It would be really good if could just run a sql query direct on the database for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best for you to create a Custom Report.

There you can run SQL queries directly on the database

[Create Reports for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Using SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx)